# Read complex objects posted with x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: node.js, express

The client is posting data to my Node/Express app using x-www-form-urlencoded for Content-Type.

I am using `body-parser`, and the data for the following incoming request can be read using `req.body.id`, `req.body.name` :

```
var item = { id: 123, name: "Abc" };
$.ajax(
 { ...,
   data: item,
   ...
 })
```

However, when the request is as follows:

```
$.ajax(
 { ...,
   data: { A: item1, B: item2 },
   ...
 })
```

where `item1` and `item2` are of the same type as the previous `item`, `req.body` now does not contain any parameterized properties.  How can I read the data in this situation?

I can see the data coming in like A[id]=123&A[name]=Abc&B[id]=123&B[name]=....

My `body-parser` is configured as follows:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
```

Comment: The output from `console.dir(A)`, `console.dir(data)` ?

Comment: Thanks! `req.body["A[Id]"]` gives me the value for `A.Id`.

Comment: How have you configured `body-parser`? Best is to set [`extended`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#extended) to `true`.

Comment: It was `false`. I now set it to `true` but the parsed output is the same as previously. I wonder what else is needed to make it work as "expected".